Admin API: Shopware 6 not updating updatedAt or triggering product.written event on order placement: Is this expected behavior?
We noticed that when an order is placed either through the storefront or via the admin panel, the product's updatedAt field does not change. Additionally, no events are triggered for product.written. Consequently, Shopware does not notify our app when the quantity changes due to orders.
Is this behavior expected?
We are considering implementing a workaround by using the checkout.order.placed event to track orders. However, ideally, we would prefer to monitor changes in the same manner as when a product is updated.
